# How accessible are the Farscape comics?

Tags: farscape

[The Beginning of the End of the Beginning](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/The_Beginning_of_the_End_of_the_Beginning) is the first comic book extension of the popular TV show *Farscape*. I've read some review of it and it supposedly starts off only a few *minutes* after the *peacekeeper wars* and doesn't get very far. Later issues of the 'main series' are then extensions into new storylines. Uncharted Tales and Scorpius also cover new topics.

For someone not having seen all of Farscape, how accessible are these comics going to be? I'm reluctant to look too far into it in case I'm spoiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty accessible if you have seen *Peacekeeper Wars* and some of the show.  As long as you know who Scorpius, John, Aeryn Sun, and Chiana are and understand their motivations you should be fine for *The Beginning of the End of the Beginning* and *Strange Detractors*.

*Gone and Back* references a plot point from episodes in the 4th season, so unless **unrealized realities** means anything to you I would wait until you catch up on the show, for that.

I would wait on reading *Tangled Roots* and the *Scorpius* forward until you have seen the show. I would also read them concurrently, as the stories interweave.

For the *Uncharted Tales* featuring D'Argo I would wait on at least until you know his true crime.  But it would probably have more impact after seeing episode 415, *Mental as Anything*.  On the other hand *Mental as Anything* might have more impact once you see the comics. But that is up to you.